# How can I turn off apheleia-mode for Latex-mode?

Tags: major-mode

I am using [apheleia](https://github.com/radian-software/apheleia) for buffer formatting.

I want to disable `apheleia-mode` for the `Latex-mode`. I have tried following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34660219/2402577) but it did not help.

> ```lisp
> (defun jpk/org-mode-hook ()
>  (company-mode -1))
> (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'jpk/org-mode-hook)
> ```

---

What I tried, which did not help:

```lisp
(apheleia-global-mode +1)
(defun app/LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  (apheleia-global-mode -1))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'app/LaTeX-mode-hook)
```

Is there any way to disable `apheleia` for a major mode like `LaTeX-mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try disabling it locally with:

```
(apheleia-global-mode +1)
(defun app/LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  (apheleia-mode -1))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'app/LaTeX-mode-hook)
```

Notice the change from `(apheleia-global-mode -1)` to `(apheleia-mode -1)`